# Scipy interpolate module not found when using executable created by cx_freeze

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, cx-freeze

I have a script that works perfectly fine when run though a command module, but when turned into an executable, it is struggling to import interpolate and signal module from scipy library.

I've searched stackoverflow with no luck; also found this thread https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/43, but either these fixes don't work for me or I'm not correctly implementing them. Interestingly, when I move "signal" folder manually out of scipy directory, the module is found, but the same solution doesn't work for interpolate.

I cannot post the project due to export control, but I am simply using `from scipy import interpolate` and this is where my script gets stuck.. Executable package is created without errors..

Example of the code

```
`def someFunction():
from scipy import interpolate
....
...
`
```

Example of setup.py file

```
`from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = ["packages":["os"],"excludes":["..."]]

executables = [Executable('...py')]

setup(name = '',
version= '',
description='',
executables=executables,
options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}
)

`
```

Python version 3.7, OS Windows 10

Thank you!

Comment: I understand the export control problems. For completeness sake, it might still help others to make a minimum reproducible example. If its really the import statement, it should not be too long.

Comment: thank you! just added - hope it will help